# How to change keys for window manipulation (from menu, default: alt+space) in openbox?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openbox, window, menu

I'd like to change default keys which manipulate window.
For example default set is:
maximize: x key
but
unmaximze: is e key
I really want to have for example x key for maximize and unmaximze.
How to change that?

**update**

I'd like to change letters binded to menu items, from 'alt + space' menu:
So..

alt + space (menu shows), then menu items are:

- 'Send to desktop' binded with 's' letter
- Layer binded with 'l' letter
- Move binded with 'm' letter
- so on..

I'd like to change these letter, like: 's', 'l' and 'm'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cannot be achieved without source modification according to:

http://icculus.org/pipermail/openbox/2013-May/007960.html

However there are 2 walkarounds:

- [one above from Varl0ck](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44539/21544)
- one with [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) + [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/) apps, like: http://icculus.org/pipermail/openbox/2013-May/007963.html

Answer (score 3):

You can find key [binding definitions here](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aBindings), And w[indow actions here.](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aActions#ToggleMaximize)

An example here to set `Ctrl + Shift + A` for toggling window maxmize state:

edit your `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`, put in these lines:

```
  <keybind key="C-S-a">
    <action name="ToggleMaximize">
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

Comment: This accomplish that but not the way, i'd like.
See updated my question.